# Which Virtual Display for UTM Ubuntu under M1 Mac?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, gpu

I was using `virtio-gpu-pci` which was running at cpu.
I want to use gpu, so I tried to change the value to `virtio-gpu-gl-pci (GPU Supported)`.
My Ubuntu runs fine, but programs no.
For example VS code is showing only window without context and for example SDRPP software is telling me:

```
[09/06/2023 18:26:37.000] [ERROR] Glfw Error 65543: GLX: Failed to create context: GLXBadFBConfig
[09/06/2023 18:26:37.000] [INFO] OpenGL 3.0 was not supported
[09/06/2023 18:26:37.000] [ERROR] Glfw Error 65543: GLX: Failed to create context: GLXBadFBConfig
[09/06/2023 18:26:37.000] [INFO] OpenGL 3.1 ES was not supported
[09/06/2023 18:26:37.000] [INFO] Using OpenGL 2.1
Failed to initialize OpenGL loader!
[09/06/2023 18:26:37.000] [WARN] Could not init using OpenGL with normal GLSL version, falling back to GLSL 1.2
Failed to initialize OpenGL loader!
[09/06/2023 18:26:37.000] [ERROR] Failed to initialize OpenGL with GLSL 1.2
```

I'm not very experienced with OpenGL, but Am I missing some stuffs?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your system is having trouble initializing OpenGL using the default `virtio-gpu-pci`.

Firstly, try using the `virtio-ramfb-gl (GPU supported)` graphics device option inside UTM for Apple Silicon. This option is designed to support GPU acceleration and might solve your issue.

If this doesn't work, you can try using the `virtio-ramfb` option instead. This option doesn't support GPU acceleration, but it might allow your software to run.

Here's how you can do it:

1. Open UTM
2. Navigate to your VM settings
3. Go to the System tab
4. Change the Graphics option to `virtio-ramfb-gl (GPU supported)`
5. Save your changes and restart your VM